# C++ fseek: Is the first byte at position 0 or 1?

Tags: c++, fseek

I want to read bytes from a file with a certain offset.

I have to do the same thing in VB6 and from C++.

For example like that:

```
FILE *file =fopen(szFileName,"rb");
fseek( file, iFirstByteToRead, SEEK_SET);
fread(nBytes,sizeof(unsigned char), iLenCompressedBytes, file);
```

(yes, I know nBytes is not declared as byte, but I named it nBytes anyway to keep my VB6 naming).

In VB6 I have to use

```
Get #iFile, iFirstByteToRead, nBytes
```

In VB6, the first byte (when using "Get") is on position 1.
This means I would have to say

```
Get #iFile, 1, nBytes
```

... to read the bytes from the very beginning of a file.

I would like to know if fseek is also 1-based or if it is 0-based.

Would I have to diminish iFirstByteToRead by -1 to get the same results?

My question is of pure theoretical nature, please don't say that my coding is bad or so...

Thank you.

Comment: "please don't say that my coding is bad or so.." - that's.. I don't even know what word to use. Anyway, as you need something "of pure theoretical nature", can't you just check the documentation of `fseek`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short terms: `fseek` offsets for a `SEEK_SET` are zero-based (e.g. `fseek(your_file, 0, SEEK_SET)` will set the stream position to the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

The first byte is at offset 0 in the file.